"This expression is not constructable" error in TypeScript dynamic property selection
First of all, I have a code like below. Here I want to dynamically select a network in a simple way.
import * as Solana from '@multiplechain/solana/node'
import * as Bitcoin from '@multiplechain/bitcoin/node'
import * as EvmChains from '@multiplechain/evm-chains/node'

export enum Type {
    COIN = Solana.types.TransactionTypeEnum.COIN,
    TOKEN = Solana.types.TransactionTypeEnum.TOKEN,
}

const networks = {
    evmchains: EvmChains,
    bitcoin: Bitcoin,
    solana: Solana,
}

export type Keys = keyof typeof networks

export const selectNetwork = (key: Keys) => networks[key]

But whenever I try to use the following, I get the following error for services.TransactionListener. Can anyone help me with this?
Error:
This expression is not constructable. Each member of the union type 'typeof TransactionListener | typeof TransactionListener | typeof TransactionListener' has construct signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.ts(2351) (property) TransactionListener: typeof TransactionListener | typeof TransactionListener | typeof TransactionListener
import { selectNetwork, Keys } from './multiplechain'
const network = selectNetwork(data.providerConfig.code as Keys)
const provider = new network.Provider(data.providerConfig as any)
const listener = new network.services.TransactionListener('COIN')


so what is TransactionListener?

@RickyMo a class

Do you know its implementation or at least the constructor definitions?

I don't know what you're saying, but I'm the creator of the relevant packs.

If you are the creator, can you show the relevant code of TransactionListener?

https://github.com/MultipleChain/js/blob/master/packages/networks/evm-chains/src/services/TransactionListener.ts

So the constructor of TransactionListener takes 3 arguments, the last 2 are optional. You provided only one argument, so it is assumed to be the 1st argument, which is type. This doesn't seem match since the 1st argument should be a TransactionTypeEnum but you are apparently providing a provider which I assume should go to the 3rd argument.

No, only the first argument is mandatory. The other two are not required. This is another error. It is not related to this one.

The first argument is mandatory but you are providing wrong type. The first argument has to be TransactionTypeEnum but you are passing a Provider to the first argument. The types don't match.

Dude, I already tried that. This error is another error.

network is of type EvmChains | Bitcont | Solana. At compile time, the compiler doesn't know exactly which type it is. Therefore, network.service. TransactionListener also has 3 possibilities. while the constructors of the 3 TransactionListener look the same, they are actually different because they accept a different Provider argument. You can try to change the Provider to ProviderInterface in all of the TransactionListener constructors.

@RickyMo yes you are right about it. There is expect their own Provider class.

May be the error arises because TypeScript cannot guarantee that the TransactionListener class constructor signatures are compatible across different network modules. To resolve this, you can cast the network services dynamically. Here is a possible solution:
import { selectNetwork, Keys } from './multiplechain';
const network = selectNetwork(data.providerConfig.code as Keys);
const provider = new network.Provider(data.providerConfig as any);

// Cast to any to bypass the construct signature issue
const listener = new (network.services as any).TransactionListener('COIN');

I hope it helps!

Yeah, I did a similar thing. I replaced the types with interfaces.
